# RegEx Help in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

My sample file is like below:

```
H343423     Something1          Something2                                                
C343423              0   
A23423432     asdfasdf sdfs 
#2342323
```

I have the following regex:

```
if (line =~ /^[HC]\d+\s/) != nil 
  puts line
end
```

Basically I want to read everything that starts with H or C and is followed by numbers and I want to stop reading when space is encountered (I want to read one word).

Output I want is:

```
H343423
C343423
```

Output my RegEx is getting is:

```
H343423     Something1          Something2                                                
C343423              0
```

So it is fetching the whole line but I just want it to stop after first word is read.

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

```
if (line =~ /^([HC]\d+)/)
  puts $1
end
```

#### For more info, see

- [Use Round Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

If you don't want to use brackets, there is special variable for the match item $&

Following will do the same

```
if line =~ /^[HC]\d+/
  puts $&
end
```

Comment: To pick up all _digits_ that follow the H or C, \d+ will work.  If you want it to stop on the first space, \S+.

Comment: ahh so () are necessary to get $1...$2 etc back

Comment: yeah @Akash, those round brackets are for [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) like $1 $2 ... etc.

Comment: @user30997, `\d+` *will* stop on the first non-digit.